# Number of ways to express a binary number in a certain way

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory, binary

So I'm working on a problem where I get to a point where I have to count the number of solutions to an equation or at least find a decent upper bound to be used in an estimate I need later.

The equation is as follows for a given $n$ and for each $k\in\{1,\dots, n-1\}$ let $S_{k}^{n}:=A^{k}\times B^{n-k}\subset\mathbb{N}^{n}$  denote the set of solutions to  the equation

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-k}b_{j}$$

where $a_{i},b_{j}\in\{2,2^2,\dots ,2^m,\dots \}$ and the $a_{i}$ and $b_{j}$ are non-decreasing ie $a_{1}\leq a_{2}\leq \dots \leq a_{k}$ and $b_{1}\leq b_{2}\leq \dots \leq b_{n-k}$.

If $(a,b)=(a_{1},\dots,a_{k},b_{1},\dots b_{n-k})$ denotes a point in $S_{k}^{n}$  and $P(a,b)$ denotes the number of unique permutations of the sequence $(a,-b)=(a_{1},\dots,a_{k},-b_{1},\dots -b_{n-k})$  then I'm trying to find a good upper bound on this sum
$$\Lambda(S_{k}^{n})=\sum_{(a,b)\in S_{k}^{n}}\left[P(a,b) \left(\prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{a_{i}} \right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n-k}\dfrac{1}{b_{j}}\right)\right].$$

So I see that this is somewhat related to the number of way that a binary number $s$ can be represented by binary digits less then $s$, I think its kinda like a partition of $s$ with only so many summands.

I'm not exactly a pro with thinking about binary digits so any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

I need this estimate so that I can show that the following sum is finite

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Lambda(S_{k}^{n})\right]<\infty$$

Comment: Just a few clarifying questions: 1) the set $S_n^k$ is meant to be infinite, yes?  2) Is $s$ an explicit parameter or did you just mean a generic integer $s$?  3) If for example, $a = (1,1)$ and $b=(2)$, then $P(a,b) = 3$?  4) Can you give any context on where the $\Lambda$ expression arose from?

Comment: @ErickWong 1) Yes $S_{n}^{k}$ will be infinite, 2) I'm not sure what you mean by is $s$ a parameter, there is not little $s$ and I'm just using the big $S_{k}^{n}$ as the set of solutions to the Diophantine equation with the $a_i$ and $b_j$ dyadic. 3) Yes that is mostly right for $a=(2,2)$ and $b=(4)$ then $P(a,b)=3$ here the $a_i,b_j\neq 1$.

Comment: 4) The expression for $\Lambda$ arose from a context in probability for a random walk where the $a_i$ represent steps to the right with "probability" $1/a_i$ and $b_j$ steps to the left with "probability" $1/b_i$ hence  with the normalization factor $\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Lambda(S_{k}^{n})$ is the probability that you return to where you start in $n$ steps.

Comment: Ah, thanks for these, it all makes sense now.  One more question, shouldn't $P(a,b)$ be the number of permutations of $(a,-b)$?  E.g. if $a = (2,2) = b$, then there are still $C(4,2)$ different orderings of the left-and-right steps, but $(2,2,2,2)$ has only one ordering, no?

Comment: @ErickWong Yes you are absolutely right it should be $(a,-b)$.

Comment: Are you sure powers of two start from 2, not from 1? As far as I understood, starting from 2¹ (instead of 2⁰ that is the standard) doesn’t change number of solutions, but looks bizarre.

Comment: Yes you are right the only real reason for this is if you start at $2^{0}$ then we end up looking at a finite measure $\mu$ with measure $2$ and if we start at $2^{1}$ we get a probability measure instead.